# Could the path to a project be defined in sln file?

Tags: c#, .net, project

When adding a new C# project to a .sln C# solution file is it possible to set the path to that project to a custom folder ? This "custom path" will be written in .sln file ?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean.  The .sln file contains the relative path to the project in question when you add the project to the solution.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add a new C# project to a .sln file in a custom folder path.

Comment: What do you mean by *custom folder path*?  You right click the solution, click Add ... Existing project, browse to it and add it.  VS will then put the path to the project in the .sln.  The project doesn't need to be under the same folder tree as the solution file (although that's generally a good idea to do).

Comment: Exactly that was my goal, so the folder tree of projects from disk may be different from the folder tree of projects from solution (sln file) and those projects will still load correctly.   "Custom folder path" represents a custom folder tree in solution that is different from the folder tree from disk which contains the project.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, the projects need to live on the exact same location on the disk that the solution is expecting to find them.  If you have a team situation where people are pulling from source control; then they should have the exact same folder structure set up.

Comment: Yes, they should have the same folder structure but, on source control is one folder structure and in solution is another one. So actually when i am adding a new project to the disc it should obey the folder structure (tree) from source control but when opening in solution the same project it should obey another folder structure (tree). And this is quite strange because when looking on disc it seems that some projects lives in "example" folder, but when opening the solution the "example" folder is not loaded and those projects occur underneath other folders.

Comment: No.. that's not the way it works.  The local disk folder structure should be identical to what is in source control.

Comment: That is true.... but i am not able to decide that, i should only add a new project under these circumstances, having one path on the source control (disc locally) and a different one in solution. Is this possible ? Could the project be loaded in that different path (tree) from solution by modifying the sln file even if on disk it lives in another path (tree)?

Comment: The solution must refer to the project based on where it actually lives.  I'm adding an answer that may clarify some of this.

Comment: Ok, so this path (tree) distinction may actually broke the build of the entire solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the extended discussion, here's the skinny.

First off, the folder structure on your file system must be identical to what is in source control; otherwise none of the references will work when someone else tries to download the project to work on it.

Let's say you have the following:

```
\Projects
    \ProjectA
        \ProjectA.csproj
    \ProjectB
        \ProjectB.csproj

\OtherProjects
    \SomethingElse
        \SomethingElse.sln
```

Now, the solution file in directory `\OtherProjects\SomethingElse\SomethingElse.sln` can refer to the project in `\Projects\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj` just fine.  Within the solution just right click on the solution file and Add... Existing Project and browse to it.  VS will add the appropriate path to the project to the file.

In Solution Explorer it will look like:

```
Solution 'SomethingElse' (1 project)
  ProjectA
```

The actual paths don't matter, except that they have to be the same between the file system and source control.

---

If you want `\Projects\ProjectA` to be physically located under `\OtherProjects\SomethingElse` then you have two options.  Either *move* the project to be under that folder OR *branch* the project to be under that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Project paths are relative to the current location of the solution file.

You can edit the paths manually if you need to move projects around after adding them to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution RightClick -> Add -> New Project -> Browse Button (near Location path)

In solution file you'll see somthing like

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectName", "{RelativePath}\ProjectName.csproj", "{050E6816-57E1-4FDB-B84B-A9C37619A312}"
```